# Determine the inverse function of $f(x)=3^{x-1}-2$

Tags: calculus

Determine the inverse function of $$f(x)=3^{x-1}-2.$$ I'm confused when you solve for the inverse you solve for $x$ instead of $y$

so would it be $x=3^{y-1}-2$?

[image]

Comment: For help writing formulas here, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Can you show me how to solve?

Comment: You are right, but this is implicit form of inverse. I think you are supposed to express $y$ from $x=3^{y-1}-2$ explicitly.

Comment: I'am not sure how to thank you enough! to all of your for your contributions :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
y=3^{x-1}-2
$$

$$
y+2=3^{x-1}/\cdot\log_3
$$

$$
\log_3(y+2)=\log_3 3^{(x-1)}
$$
$$
\log_3(y+2)=x-1
$$
$$
x=\log_3 (y+2)+1
$$

Now we take the substituon $x=y^{-1}$, and we have
$$
y^{-1}=\log_3 (x+2)+1
$$

Answer (score 1):

In case of inverse you find $x$ in terms of y.

First you note that the inverse exists(monotonic function) then you do the following.

$y=3^{x-1}-2\Rightarrow y+2=3^{x-1}\Rightarrow \log_3(y+2)=x-1\Rightarrow x=\log_3(y+2)+1$

And you are done.(As a customary one needs to replace x with y as we generally denote a function by y with independent variable x)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right till here. Recall that you have to solve for $y$ and finally replace $y $ with $f^{-1}(x)$ and $x$ with $y$.
$$x = 3^{y-1} - 2$$
Just add $2$ and take log base 3 on both sides.$$\begin{align} &x + 2 = 3^{y-1} \\  \Rightarrow & \log_3(x + 2) = y - 1 \\ \Rightarrow & y = \log_3(x + 2) + 1  \end{align}$$And you have $f^{-1}(x) = \log_3(x + 2) + 1$. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

To find the inverse function $f^{-1}$ in the form $y = f^{-1}(x)$, there are two things you can do:

1) Switch $x$ and $y$, and then solve for $y$.

2) Solve for $x$, and then switch $x$ and $y$.

You seem to be trying to switch $x$ and $y$ and then solve for $x$.  You need to solve for $y$ if you've already switched the variables.  See the methods (1) and (2) above.

Answer (score 1):

To find the inverse start by writing $y=3^{x-1}-2$. Now, can you rearrange it so you get $x=\ldots$ ?

For example $y+2 = 3^{x-1}$. Then how do you "unpick" a power? You take the logarithm:

\begin{array}{ccc}
y+2 &=& 3^{x-1} \\ \log_3(y+2) &=& \log_3(3^{x-1}) \\ \log_3(y+2) &=& x-1
\end{array}

Finally, $x=\log_3(y+2)+1$. Your inverse function is then $\operatorname{f}^{-1}(x) = \log_3(x+2)+1$.

Answer (score 0):

it's right, but I think you need simplify it. $y=log_3(x+2)+1$

Comment: It's not right. The OP's suggestion does not simplify to what you have written.

Comment: I checked, and I think it is right. I am not a native english user, what does "OP's suggestion" mean? thx!

Comment: OP stands for Original Post or Original Poster. This is common in forums. Hence "The OP's suggestion" means "the suggestion made in the original post". The OP's suggestion was that $x=3^{y-1}-2$ is the inverse of $y=3^{x-1}-2$. This is clearly false.

Comment: @robjohn Perhaps we have a different idea of what "inverse" means. As I said in my post $\operatorname{f}^{-1}(x) = \log_3(x+2)+1$. The OP asks if the inverse would be $x=3^{y-1}-2$. This is not the inverse. That is the first step towards finding the inverse. The OP still needs to rearrange and solve for $y$. Writing $x=3^{y-1}-2$ for the inverse of $\operatorname{f}(x) = 3^{x-1}-2$ would not, under any mark scheme that I am aware of, gain full marks.

Comment: @robjohn Having said that, I realise what delta meant now. "Yes, that's right, that's the first step. Now rearrange to find the inverse." My apologies for the misunderstanding. I'll delete my comments shortly.